# Get size of Parent Container for Fragment in Java for Android

Tags: java, android, webview, fragment, parent-child

I have a Class in Java that creates a fragement with a webview inside.
If I want that fragment to fill the parent container in the Main Activity I set the parameters width and height to MATCH_PARENT.

But for those cases where I need it to fill 50% width and/or a certain number of pixels height I need the size of that parent container.
If I Log the MATCH_PARENT value it returns -1.

I would like to have one of these 2 options:

1 – Get the size of the parent container

2 – Get the size of the screen minus the interface menu.

Here's a  visual example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Android dynamic fragment]

EDIT: Here's my code:

Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
myContainer = new ShowContainer("myId", getSupportFragmentManager());
}
```

Class:

```
public class ShowContainer {
public ShowContainer(String id, FragmentManager fm){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, new loadView());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
public static class loadView extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        GridLayout fl = new GridLayout(this.getActivity());
        WebView webView = new WebView(this.getActivity());
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        params.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        params.width = MATCH_PARENT;
        params.height = MATCH_PARENT;
        params.topMargin = 0;
        params.leftMargin = 0;
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
        webView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return fl;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some code man

Comment: You want the fragment's height to be variable say 50% or some pixel value? Or the fragment should be MATCH_PARENT with Webview having some specific height?

Comment: The fragment size should be variable. Sometimes it will be a percentage of the parent. Other times it might be a fixed pixel size. The webview will fill that fragment. The position in the screen will also be variable.

Comment: And how are you adding the fragment to activity?

Comment: I'm adding the fragment to the main activity like this: myContainer = new ShowContainer("myId", getSupportFragmentManager());

Comment: The container to which you are adding the fragment, just give it the desired height? And keep your fragment height to MATCH_PARENT? You can get the parent activity's root view's height easily using getHeight() in a viewTreeObserver. Using that height assign the desired height to the container that would host the fragment.

Comment: I need to do that from inside the Class because the size (percentage or fixed) will be coming from a json call.

Comment: In that case, create a method in parent activity that would resize the view that hosts the fragment. And call that method from your fragment.

Comment: I need to keep the parent activity as clean as possible. Can I pass that activity as a parameter to the class when I instantiate it? That way I would then check its size and perform all calculations from inside the ShowContainer class.

Comment: There is no need to pass activity as a parameter. You can always access the parent activity using getActivity(). If you only need parent activity height in fragment, you can pass height as a parameter or in a bundle when you are adding the fragment to activity.